# How to receive a value returned by a Solidity smart contract transacting function?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, rsk

I am writing an [NFT smart contract](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721URIStorage) which I am going to  test via [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) and deploy on [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/).

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    uint private _counter;
    address private _owner;

    constructor() ERC721("My NFT", "MNFT") {
      _owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
      return _owner;
    }

    function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
        public returns (uint256)
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner(), "Only owner is allowed to mint");
        uint newItemId = ++_counter;
        ERC721._mint(recipient, newItemId);
        ERC721URIStorage._setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Here I have two public functions: `owner` and `mintNFT` both returning some values. In my tests I would like to read the return values coming from these two functions. These are the tests I am running on Hardhat:

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("My NFT", () => {
  let deployer;
  let myNFT;

  // deploy NFT before the tests
  before(async () => {
    [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const MyNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyNFT');
    myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy();
    await myNFT.deployed();
  });

  describe('Receiving a value returned by a view function', () => {
    it('The deployer should be the s/c owner', async  () => {
      const owner = await myNFT.owner();
      expect(owner).to.equal(deployer.address);
    });
  });
  
  describe('Receiving a value returned by a transacting function', () => {
    it('Should return a correct ID of the newly minted item', async () => {
      const newMintItem = {
        id: 1,
        uri: 'ipfs://Qme3QxqsJih5psasse4d2FFLFLwaKx7wHXW3Topk3Q8b14',
      };
      const newItemId = await myNFT.mintNFT(deployer.address, newMintItem.uri);
      expect(newItemId).to.equal(newMintItem.id);
    });
  });
});
```

In the case of the `owner` function I get what I expect: It returns my account address, and the first test passes successfully. However, when it comes to the `mintNFT` function, I don't get what I expect: Instead of the newly created item ID I get something very different and my second test fails.

Why do two very similar tests give me different results? How do I get a return value from a function that sends a transaction?
For reference, this is the `hardhat.config.js` file I'm using:

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  defaultNetwork: 'rskregtest',
  networks: {
    rskregtest: {
      chainId: 33,
      url: 'http://localhost:4444',
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: What is the result of the 2nd test?

Answer (score 14):

Values returned from a transaction are not available outside of EVM.

You can either emit an event, or create a public `view` getter function of the value.

```
contract MyNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    // `public` visibility autogenerates view function named `_counter()`
    uint public _counter;
    event NFTMinted(uint256 indexed _id);

    function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
        public returns (uint256)
    {
        // ...
        emit NFTMinted(newItemId);
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

```js
it('Should return a correct ID of the newly minted item', async () => {
    const newMintItem = {
        id: 1,
        uri: 'ipfs://Qme3QxqsJih5psasse4d2FFLFLwaKx7wHXW3Topk3Q8b14',
    };

    // testing the emitted event
    await expect(myNFT.mintNFT(deployer.address, newMintItem.uri))
        .to.emit(myNFT, "NFTMinted")
        .withArgs(newMintItem.id);

    // testing the getter value
    const counter = await myNFT._counter();
    expect(counter).to.equal(newMintItem.id);
});
```

Docs: https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#emitting-events

Answer (score 11):

You can not directly receive a return value coming from a function that you are sending a transaction to off-chain. You can only do so on-chain - i.e. when one SC function invokes another SC function.

However, in this particular case, you can obtain the value through events, as the [ERC721 specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification) includes a `Transfer` event:

```
    /// @dev This emits when ownership of any NFT changes by any mechanism.
    ///  This event emits when NFTs are created (`from` == 0) and destroyed
    ///  (`to` == 0). Exception: during contract creation, any number of NFTs
    ///  may be created and assigned without emitting Transfer. At the time of
    ///  any transfer, the approved address for that NFT (if any) is reset to none.
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);
```

In [Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/), which you are already using in your hardhat tests, instead of smart contract function return value, you get a [transaction response object](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionResponse) returned on this line:

```js
const txResponse = await myNFT.mintNFT(deployer.address, newMintItem.uri);
```

Next you need to get a [transaction receipt](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionReceipt) by calling `wait` on `txResponse`:

```js
const txReceipt = await txResponse.wait();
```

In turn, `txReceipt` contains an `events` array which includes all events emitted by your transaction. In this case, expect it to include a single `Transfer` event indicating the first minted item transfer from the [zero address](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/constants/#constants-AddressZero) to your account address. Get this event by extracting the first element from the `events` array:

```js
const [transferEvent] = txReceipt.events;
```

Next take `tokenId` property from the `transferEvent` arguments and this will be the Id of your newly minted NFT:

```js
const { tokenId } = transferEvent.args;
```

The whole test should look as follows:

```js
describe('Receiving a value returned by a transacting function', () => {
    it('Should return a correct ID of the newly minted item', async () => {
      const newMintItem = {
        id: 1,
        uri: 'ipfs://QmY6KX35Rg25rnaffmZzGUFb3raRhtPA5JEFeSSWQA4GHL',
      };
      const txResponse = await myNFT.mintNFT(deployer.address, newMintItem.uri);
      const txReceipt = await txResponse.wait();
      const [transferEvent] = txReceipt.events;
      const { tokenId } = transferEvent.args;
      expect(tokenId).to.equal(newMintItem.id);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the return value of the function if you use `callStatic`, like so:

`const newItemId = await myNFT.callStatic.mintNFT(deployer.address, newMintItem.uri);`

you just have to remember that `callStatic` only simulates the function call and returns the return value, but it doesn't change the contract state (so basically after the static call it is as if it didn't happen) so you can't use it if you want to check any subsequent consequences.

https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-callStatic